# How can I find out what's waking up my ultrabook?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, windows-8.1, sleep

So I just got a new machine and I noticed when I woke up the next day that the screen was on, meaning it somehow woke itself up on sleep.  I had already disabled the waking options for mice and keyboards in their respective locations. Wifi was not enabled, but for good measure, I checked the settings for that network adapter as well and afaik, there is no option for wake on that device. There is no ethernet chip, so it can't be that either.  I also went through every task in the task manager, including all the default Microsoft and Sony ones to make sure that they don't have wake up the machine to run the task enabled.

In the event viewer, under System, I can see the following:

[image]

By testing sleep and wake manually, I have come to the conclusion that event ID 507 is wake and 506 is sleep.  It does not seem to have the standard event ID 1.  I've checked application logs, but nothing seems to happen within a minute of the wake event.

Another thing I've noticed is that plugging and unplugging the charger will wake it, but the charger cord is pretty snug and it doesn't seem to be that (though I do want to disable this if anyone knows how to).  So how can I further troubleshoot what's causing the wakes?

Edit: Not conclusive, but I checked on the wireless adapter again but now I do see some options for wake. I found Wake on pattern match, Wake on RSN Rekey, and Wake-Up Mode.  I disabled pattern match and rsn rekey just now, so I'm hoping that resolves it.  Wake-up Mode has the following available values: All, LossOfLink, None, Wake Up Frame, WakeUpPkt & Linkloss.  If I set it to None, I can no longer put the machine to sleep, so that's probably not an option.  Any ideas to what these are?  Hopefully, the first two options fix the issue, but I'm still suspecting not as I did not have wireless enabled..

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for wake timers: Run > Command Prompt (Admin)

> powercfg /waketimers

2. If any shares are hosted, and once they are accessed form other computers, the machine could wake up.
3. Disable *"Allow this device to wake this computer"* for all USB devices if you are using wireless Mouse, if any.

Comment: 1: There are no active wake timers in the system. 2: There are no shares. 3: No devices were connected.

Comment: @Daniel Check Scheduled tasks and check if any tasks has "Wake the computer to run this task" enabled. Maybe a windows backup or time sync is scheduled. Also check if any Automatic Maintenance is enabled.

Comment: I clearly stated in my question that I had checked every single task for that option and none of them had it enabled.  Please clarify what you mean by automatic maintenance.

Comment: On windows 8: [1](http://imgur.com/2ZZkfZa) Check if this is disabled.

Comment: Yes, it is disabled. Going to edit in some additional information that I found.

Comment: Also try disabling all the **Power ON** options in BIOS. This should override all windows settings. Also try 'powercfg -devicequery wake_armed' in commandline to check if any other devices trigger the wake; just to be sure.

Comment: There are no such options in BIOS.  That query also returns none.  powercfg lastwake does not work either.  I think that may be due to the wakeup event being 507 instead of the standard 1.  It doesn't seem to be counted as a regular sleep.